# Isn't it time to set the bar higher to obtain moderation tools?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, moderation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Make Moderator abilities relate to Rep Inflation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28232/make-moderator-abilities-relate-to-rep-inflation)
>   [What to do about rep inflation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/what-to-do-about-rep-inflation)

As the SO is growing the number of users with more than 3K rep is also growing. I believe that because of this even some valid questions are getting closed simply because there are too many people with the power to close them. So shouldn't the bar be set a bit higher (say 6K reps) to keep these close voters at bay?

Comment: There is a dupe here somewhere, looking.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28232/make-moderator-abilities-relate-to-rep-inflation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No; with the same reasoning, there will be more people to vote for reopening questions.

Moreover, as the number of participants in SO grows, the number of posts grows proportionally. Ultimately, the ratio of users to posts will not change significantly.

Comment: Nicely put, way to nail the fallacy!

Comment: Interesting stats question: how has the ratio of users over 3k to numbers of posts changed over time?

Comment: Ether: "Over time" questions are hard to answer with data dump. A single data dump lacks historical reputation records.